# ColumnCount in DataGridView remains 0 after assigning data source

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I am having trouble with the following simple code

```
BindingList<Car> tempList = new BindingList<Car>();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = tempList;
dgTempView.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Here, dgTempView is a data grid view
After the above lines execute, the column count in the datagrid view remains 0. And when I try adding a Car instance in tempList, I get an error saying that 'no row can be added to a datagridview control that does not have columns' . I am not able to understand what am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake. The members of the Class Car were public instance variables and not properties. The moment I changed them to Auto Properties it worked :)